# MySQL/PHP - Include a new parameter key/value pair in hierarchical JSON

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL query which produces hierarchical JSON with some help from PHP.

What I would like is a new 'parameter' key/value pair **ONLY** where the type = unit. Like `"type":"unit", "parameter":"xyz"` as in:

```
{
    "name": "PATH5121 Clinical Biochemistry",
    "column_to_sort_by": "PATH5121 Clinical Biochemistry",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "Learning Events - PATH5121",
            "column_to_sort_by": null,
            "type": "unit_group"
        },
        {
            "name": "Assessments - PATH5121",
            "column_to_sort_by": null,
            "type": "unit_group"
        }
    ],
    "type": "unit",
    "parameter": "xyz"
}
```

E.g.: this is the relevant part of the current query:

```
...
UNION ALL
SELECT 
       CONCAT('year:', u.year_fk, ',unit:', u.unit_full_name) AS global_id,
       u.unit_full_name,
       CONCAT('year:', u.year_fk) AS parent_global_id,
       
       NULL AS column_to_sort_by
FROM unit u
UNION ALL
...
```

The PHP section after the query:

```
$result = $connection->query($query);
$data = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    $data[$row->global_id] = $row;
}

$roots = array();
foreach ($data as $row) {   
    $row->type = end(explode(",",(implode(array_slice(explode ( ':',  $row->global_id), -2, 1)))));
    if ($row->parent_global_id === null) {
        $roots[]= $row;
    } else {
        $data[$row->parent_global_id]->children[] = $row;
    }
    unset($row->parent_global_id);
    unset($row->global_id);
}

$json = json_encode($roots);

$json = trim($json, '[]');

$fp = fopen('data.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $json);
fclose($fp);
```

The PHP adds a key/value pair to the JSON named 'type' for each of the structural parts of the JSON.  'type' get its value from the table name.  Possibly the way to include the new key/value pair above is to do something similar.  Not sure how to do that.

A snippet from the existing JSON:

```
{
    "name": "PATH5121 Clinical Biochemistry",
    "column_to_sort_by": "PATH5121 Clinical Biochemistry",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "Learning Events - PATH5121",
            "column_to_sort_by": null,
            "type": "unit_group"
        },
        {
            "name": "Assessments - PATH5121",
            "column_to_sort_by": null,
            "type": "unit_group"
        }
    ],
    "type": "unit"
}
```

The structure of table `unit` has the following relevant columns:

`unit_pk` Index for table unit

`unit_full_name` Currently included in the JSON for table unit.  Eg as in the example above 'PATH5121 Clinical Biochemistry'

`development_level`. This is the new 'parameter' key/value I want included.

see [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3xy96hwyCcd4n6jSBLFx52/1)

Comment: ??? MySQL have a lot of [JSON functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-function-reference.html) - use them and not `CONCAT`. And you'd not need in PHP code.

Comment: Yes, I know, but it's not my call.  I have to modify the existing.

Comment: Kind of confused by the question, but is [this](https://onlinephp.io/c/6f6c1) what you are trying todo?

Comment: @Crimin4L  Maybe, looks like it's in the right direction, but I think a solution will require the tables and data, and the complete MySQL query to work with.  I will post that to the OP soon...

Comment: DB fiddle added.  See end of OP.  Ask any questions or continue to chat.

Comment: What are you trying todo with the array after you add the new parameter? That's where I am getting lost. Do you want to turn it back into JSON and insert it into the database? Or do you want to cycle through the JSON and insert the data individually; if the latter, you should do what @Rick_James suggested as that is the easiest way.

Comment: @Crimin4L  The data from the query (see fiddle) is being converted to JSON, which is used for a d3.js mapping tree.  In the d3.js code for the tree, I want to check in unit data for a value.  That value comes from a column in the unit table (see fiddle) 'development_level'.  I need to add that column in the MySQL unit data (see query in fiddle).  Currently only unit_full_name is in that unit data.  I want to add 'development_level' as a new key/value pair - we can call this key 'parameter'...

Comment: ...that new key/value pair needs to be added to the JSON output where the type = unit.  But u.development_level must only be in the JSON as a parameter key for the unit structure in the JSON...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Concept

The idea is that UNION cannot work with a different amount of columns. This will result in the following error:

```
Query Error: Error: ER_WRONG_NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS_IN_SELECT: The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns
```

Therefor we set the `parameter` column in each UNION ALL statement. This can be null or a value depending on the requirements.

In the PHP code, if the `parameter` field equals null, we simply unset it. The result is a json string
which contains an extra parameter column when the value of parameter is not empty.

### Change the sql to

See the columns with comment `-- added this column`.

```sql
SELECT CONCAT('program:', p.program_pk) AS global_id,
       p.program_name AS name,
       NULL AS parent_global_id,   
       NULL AS column_to_sort_by ,
       null as parameter  -- added this column 
FROM program p
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT('year:', y.year_pk) AS global_id,
       y.year_name,
       CONCAT('program:', y.program_fk) AS parent_global_id,       
         NULL AS column_to_sort_by,
       null as parameter -- added this column 
FROM year y 

UNION ALL
SELECT 
       CONCAT('year:', u.year_fk, ',unit:', u.unit_full_name) AS global_id,
       u.unit_full_name,
       CONCAT('year:', u.year_fk) AS parent_global_id,   
       NULL AS column_to_sort_by,
       'xyz' as parameter -- added this column 
FROM unit u

UNION ALL
SELECT 
       CONCAT('year:', u2.year_fk, ',unit:', u2.unit_full_name, ',unit_group:', ug.unit_group) AS global_id,
       ug.unit_group,
       CONCAT('year:', u2.year_fk, ',unit:', u2.unit_full_name) AS parent_global_id,
       
       NULL AS column_to_sort_by,
       null as parameter -- added this column 
FROM unit_group ug
INNER JOIN unit u2 ON u2.unit_pk = ug.unit_fk

UNION ALL
SELECT 
       CONCAT('year:', u3.year_fk, ',unit:', u3.unit_full_name, ',unit_group:', ug2.unit_group, ',week:', wk.week) AS global_id,
       wk.week,
       CONCAT('year:', u3.year_fk, ',unit:', u3.unit_full_name, ',unit_group:', ug2.unit_group) AS parent_global_id,
       
       NULL AS column_to_sort_by,
       null as parameter -- added this column 
FROM week wk
INNER JOIN unit_group ug2 ON ug2.unit_group_pk = wk.unit_group_fk
INNER JOIN unit u3 ON u3.unit_pk = ug2.unit_fk
UNION ALL
    SELECT 
           CONCAT('year:', u3.year_fk, ',unit:', u3.unit_full_name, ',unit_group:', ug2.unit_group, ',week:', wk2.week,  ',learning_event:', le.learning_event_name) AS global_id,
           le.learning_event_name,
           CONCAT('year:', u3.year_fk, ',unit:', u3.unit_full_name, ',unit_group:', ug2.unit_group, ',week:', wk2.week) AS parent_global_id,
           
           le.learning_event_name AS column_to_sort_by,
       null as parameter -- added this column 
    FROM learning_event le
    INNER JOIN week wk2 ON wk2.week_pk = le.week_fk
    INNER JOIN unit_group ug2 ON ug2.unit_group_pk = wk2.unit_group_fk
    INNER JOIN unit u3 ON ug2.unit_fk = u3.unit_pk
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
           CONCAT('year:', u3.year_fk, ',unit:', u3.unit_full_name, ',unit_group:', ug2.unit_group, ',assessment:', t1.assessment) AS global_id,
            t1.assessment,
           CONCAT('year:', u3.year_fk, ',unit:', u3.unit_full_name, ',unit_group:', ug2.unit_group) AS parent_global_id,
           
           t1.assessment AS column_to_sort_by,
       null as parameter -- added this column 
    FROM assessment t1
    INNER JOIN unit_group ug2 ON ug2.unit_group_pk = t1.unit_group_fk
    INNER JOIN unit u3 ON ug2.unit_fk = u3.unit_pk
```

### Change the following PHP lines

```php
while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    $data[$row->global_id] = $row;
}
```

to:

```php
while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    if($row->parameter === null) {
        unset($row->parameter);
    }
    $data[$row->global_id] = $row;
}
```

Comment: This looks good and could prove to be exceptionally useful, but I haven't tested yet. For 'xyz' as parameter -- added this column, to substitute a value from the relevant table column, unit.development_level, how would I do that?  It would be u.development_level, but how should I include that column instead of the static value 'xyz'?

Comment: Yep, changing to ''xyz' as parameter' to 'u.development_level' as parameter works!  Brilliant.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend working with the JSON functions for anything non-trivial.

Instead, read a record(s) from the table, use PHP's `json_decode()` to turn it into a PHP structure, manipulate that structure, then use `json_encode()` and write back to the table.

I think you will find PHP coding more flexible.

Comment: Thanks but can you provide a solution to get u.development_level into the JSON like $row->type has been done in the PHP above?  Obviously that column would need to be in the MySQL query, but l need an answer for that as well please.  I'm after a specific solution.